# Synonym for Boolean

Tags: synonyms

**Question**

I am trying to find a word, other than `Boolean`, that represents a true or false value. Is there such a word?

**Context**

I am designing a programming language that is meant to be as easy as possible to understand for those who know nothing of programming. I am trying to name the fundamental types in a way that portrays their purpose to the target audience well. For example, instead of `float` or even `floating-point number`, the data type is called `decimal`. After much thought and use of a popular search engine, I cannot think of an alternative to `Boolean` for true or false values.

The reason I do not wish to use `Boolean` is that people who have not been exposed to programming or similar logical thinking simply do not know what it is, which is exactly what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: For various reasons I often needed programming variables that simply had to be switched between one of two possible values (usually, but not always, True/False or 0/1). In the end I just defined a class called TOGGLE to handle it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers that's a great one, thank you! Togglable (or maybe switch?) is definitely easy for anyone to understand, even if it is a bit of a mouthful.

Comment: flip‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎flop

Comment: @OMGtechy: I'm not sure why you need to think in terms of *togglable/toggleable* anyway. If one of your other datatypes is *decimal*, does that imply any need for people using your language to get to grips with *decimalisable?*

Comment: @FumbleFingers good point, it just worked better in my mind when I was writing the comment for some reason.

Comment: @tchrist well it certainly sounds good!

Comment: **This is not an answer to your question about English:** Alternatively you may consider making a *dynamically typed programming language*. The first language that I learned was Logo (turtle language?) in primary school (5th year). It really doesn't have data types. It just checks types in run time.

Comment: @ABC I remember Logo! And yes that's true, although the user may wish to print the value as a specified type, in which case they'd still need a name for it (for example, `print myVar as Boolean`).

Comment: We use the term `flag` a lot, in the same sense as 'Toggle', but it seems to evoke the 'true when waving' idea

Comment: @Gus thank you, not sure what you mean by the true when waving thing though?

Comment: decimal is a formatting convention, not a storage type.

Comment: @Oldcat True, but if your new programmer sees decimal they'll know what it does. What's more, it could be cast to other formatting conventions upon request.

Comment: You will have types based on formats?  And I disagree that decimal gives anyone, programmers and non programmers the idea of floating point data.  It really doesn't say much to anyone.  Other "simple" languages have just used doubles with everything and dispensed with all other numeric types.

Comment: @Oldcat this is still at design time and subject to extensive changes, but from speaking to my target market/group (since this isn't and never will be a commercial venture) decimal has been the most effective for floating point numbers, and `myDecimal as Octal` and so on for when another representation was needed.

Comment: The times you want to write a floating point number in another base is basically 0.  It is integral types that you do that.

Comment: @Oldcat then why are you complaining about me using the most commonly understood floating point representation?

Comment: Is your floating point stored in base 2? (e.g., is it an IEEE floating point?) (If so, "decimal" is a terrible name.) Most "decimal" types in programming languages store their value in base-10, trading a bit of performance for being able to store whole (decimal) digits. (As opposed to a binary type, which will store fractional decimal digits.) (Also, in this regard, it's not just a "formatting convention": it directly relates to how the value is stored, which has consequences on what values are representable by the type.)

Comment: I think Oldcat is giving you a bit of a hard time because it's not clear that you've thought things through. To me, the major point to take away from his comments (and certainly the most constructive) is not about whether *decimal* is more intuitive to lay people than *float*. It's about whether to have more than one numeric data type at all. (Others have commented in this direction as well.) At least, I'm assuming you will have more than one, because if *decimal* is going to be your *only* numeric type, then I have to ask why you didn't simply pick *number* as its name instead.

Comment: @JohnY It's at the very early stages, but I do see the point. At the moment, I've done something similar to what you mentioned in the end; I have a `Number` type that has a `Whole` type modifier instead of `Integer` and some representation of a float separately.

Comment: I don't mean to belabor the point or start a conversation here[1] but what the heck is a "type modifier"? That sounds complicated to me, and I've got a computer science degree and program for a living (and for fun). [1]So I created a chat room [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14156/programming-language-for-lay-people) instead.

Comment: @JohnY I struggle to believe you can work as a programmer and not know what a type modifer is. http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/c/9788131729342/data-types-variables-and-constants/type_qualifiers_and_type_modifiers

Comment: The point of my asking is that your *target audience* is going to ask what a type modifier is. And yes, I don't know what a type modifier is... in **your proposed language**. I'm fine with `const` or `short` or `long` or `private` or whatever. But you're telling me that you are designing a language for people who will have trouble picking up `Boolean`, and it not only has types, but type modifiers? (OK, I see you're in the chat, so we'll continue this there.)

Comment: The basic meaning of "Boolean" is having something to do with George Boole, as in Boolean algebra, Boolean lattice and so forth. Can't you just say "two-valued?"

Comment: I don't understand this question at all. How can there be a synonym for a proper noun like this? Is there a synonym for Euclidean geometry or Einsteinian physics?? Linguistically speaking, not programming-wise....

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Binary - in the sense of two values, but perhaps still too computer-y a word.

Logical - which has a history of being used in FORTRAN and some COBOLs, and thus might represent a less influenced way of discussing these values.

Truth, Truth-Value - as in whether or not something is true, rather that what is or is not in fact true.  That is what Boole called them, after all, and we then named them after him.

Dichotomy / Dichotomous - again, having two values, but also linked to logic more than math.

The same goofy Lisp people who first called the pound sign 'hash', the period 'dot' and the exclamation point 'bang', did so in the same spirit you are working in.  They also marked Boolean valued functions with a 'P' (because it looked like a '?') and referred to them as "whether" functions, as in 'whether or not'...

Comment: Thanks for your help. The only issue I have with binary is that it implies that the data is stored in a bit. It is certainly the best I've heard so far though and more intuitive than Boolean. It amazes me that it's so hard to think of a common English world for this!

Comment: My, you are quick.  I don't know whether I added the last one before or after you replied.  It might actually be the best option, as it captures the logic.  But is seems a bit precious.

Comment: Truth is quite good too, but the down side of that is it implies an immutable true. Truth-Value doesn't imply it quite as strongly though. Dichotomy has the same problem as Boolean. (Sorry if I seem critical, I am very grateful for your help). I'll have to run these past a few people non-programmers and see what they think.

Comment: The other answer (which has now been removed?) had Logical, you might want to add that to your answer since it was a good idea and a shame for anyone else asking the same question to miss.

Comment: @OMGtechy The problem with binary is that you are not conveying the data type properly. I think *truth value* is the more appropriate. This also allows for hinting at having different implementations of what truth value is. You could have a boolean truth value (boolean inheriting from truth value), but you could also have other classes of truth values that allow other implementations, like if you want to work with modal logic.

Comment: @ABC I agree with you on the data type point. And that's interesting, I'll have to look into that.

Comment: @OMGtechy For instance. TruthValue is a class of data that provides certain basic functions (say negate[NOT], or maybe also conjunction[AND], disjuction[OR], etc). But then a BooleanTruthValue inherits from TruthValue and implements these operations in the usual way. But then, one could have BelnapTruthValue which inherits from TruthValue but implements those functions in some other way (as in [Belnap logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-valued_logic)). Well, now I read that this is for an introductory programming language. Maybe so much functionality is too much.

Comment: @ABC Whilst it is indeed aimed at total novices, being more flexible is certainly not a bad thing in this case.

Comment: @OMGtechy your first comment made me smile. I find it interesting how you assume that people who don't know *Boolean* (and can't be bothered to look it up) will be familiar with the concept of a *bit*. Or *storage*, for that matter. Come to think of it, even *data* and *imply* are pretty big words. If "binary implies that the data is stored in a bit" to you, then here's ten dollars that you've heard *Boolean* already. So the way I see it, out of all suggestions here only *Truth-Value* is remotely useful at all. Binary? P? Dichoto-wut? You man serious?

Comment: @RegDwigнt I did not imply that the *user* would be familiar with the concept of a bit when starting. However, once the user is more familiar they may *later* assume that such a value is stored as a bit (as I used to with Booleans when I began programming, only Binary even more strongly suggests this). TruthValue is a good candidate, I agree.

Comment: Right Logical is one I have forgotten, it has a history of use before Boolean caught on.

One assumes that a good implementation of TruthValue in general could, in fact not be stored in a bit.  It would probably have to allow a value of Unknown, so it would need at least two.  I am still quite keen on Whether, but I go for cute.  Think of the declaration.  String name, Number dependents, Whether isRegistered, ...

Comment: Accepting this as the answer as it more directly answers the question. However, I am very thankful for everyones contributions!

Comment: @JonJayObermark `Whether Foo IsAlive`...nice

Comment: The "P" for Boolean functions might stand for "Predicate".

Comment: Since this is a technical question And I am dealing with a CS problem to convey a concept that is opposite of Boolean, which word should I use? Question details: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/594737/386678

Answer (score 4):

In my programming days I thought of these as **Yes/No** values: declared global constants `Yes` and `No`, with values appropriate to the language (usually 1 and 0), named variables which bore these values `FooYN`, with Foo representing an appropriate name for the True state (e.g. `OnYN`, `DoneYN`) , and if the language supported it declared a YesNo type with two possible values, `Yes` and `No`. I found it made my code a tad more readable.

Comment: + 1. I like this. I'll have to go through all the best candidates with some members of the target audience and mark an answer based upon what they prefer in practice.

Comment: Late to the game as always, but I like where this one goes, and I would call it a 'maybe' value. Because until you know at runtime whether it is 'yes' or 'no', it's just 'maybe'.

Comment: @tuespetre Yah; but if 'maybe' is an ***option***, if you actually don't know the value at runtime, then you've gone trivalent: you have to include an 'undefined' value. Is it still a 'boolean' then?

Comment: @StoneyB ‘maybe’ is a symbol for an indeterminate value that is binary at evaluation time. It’s like there’s a ‘stack’ or ‘scheme’, where in one locale (in this case an unbound environment) it is ternary but in another it is binary.

Answer (score 3):

I've seen the word **flag** used, and I like it a lot. Wonder why it hasn't been said here.

Comment: "flag" is jargon and not really better than "boolean", in my opinion.

Comment: Eh.  Its cultural references are to train lines and mailboxes, right?  So it may be stuck in time.  As its original references disappear, it may be becoming less of a metaphor and more of a fixed jargon word.  (Like radio-button: I've seen literal, physical radio buttons, but my nieces haven't.  When they see them on the screen, there is no metaphor, that is just what they call them.)

Answer (score 2):

Would constative apply?

**Constative**: [being or relating to an utterance (as an assertion, question, or command) that is capable of being judged true or false](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/constative)

Comment: It terms of meaning it's great, but sadly is no more intuitive than Boolean.

Answer (score 2):

A word or expression for "boolean" that is easily identifiable by those who know nothing of programming?

You might pretty well have named that expression already.

> [True/false values](http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/notes/sx3c.html).

Comment: By this are you referring to having Integer implicitly cast to a Boolean like C and C++ do? If so...interesting; I could eliminate the type altogether.

Comment: @OMGtechy I'm pretty sure that he's just saying that "true/false values" would be an expression that means "boolean".  Personally, I'd advise against using implicit casts from integer to boolean for a beginner language as the sole determiner.  It leads to confusion for when a person uses a negative number vs 0 vs positive number.  And what if they cast a non-int to an int and then treat it like a bool (say, casting a char to an int)?  Much confusion for new users.

Answer (score 2):

how about a `yesno` it has easy mnemonics and it's easy to understand. sometimes you have to invent words, that's being done all the time in programming languages :)

Source: IT Professional

Answer (score 2):

How about `switch`, as in a light switch, which can be either on or off?  The only problem is that this is used in many programming languages for multiple choice selections.

Comment: This is the only one that I was ever comfortable with, especially when I had to deal with other dualities.

Comment: Some switches have more than 2 values or positions.

Answer (score 0):

A **Proposition**:

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proposition)

*Aristotelian logic identifies a proposition as a sentence which affirms or denies a predicate of a subject. An Aristotelian proposition may take the form "All men are mortal" or "Socrates is a man."*

Answer (score 0):

This may be too late but anyway... I think the word 'Trueness' could be the one that you look for. 'Trueness' can be considered as a state to be or not to be True.

Comment: Welcome to ELU, please consider adding sources to support your answers. In this case, I don't think _trueness_ encapsulates that is binary (i.e. either true or false).

Comment: I found this answer useful in my hunt to name an `enum` type with 3 fixed values - `Default`, `False`, `True`. You used the word **state** and that was it. Thanks.