# Antonym of 'Boolean'

Tags: synonyms, antonyms

A Boolean variable has either 0 or 1 as its value. (correct me if I'm wrong) If 'Boolean' is used as an adjective, it means, either that entity exists or does not exist (but no both). For [example](https://www.productlineengineering.com/concepts/features.html):

> A Boolean feature is a feature that may be present or absent [not both] in the final product. Example: the feature "Moon roof" would be type Boolean, since it's either in or out.

However, I'm dealing with some features that either exist, does not exist, or their multiple copies exist. For example, a railway station consists of signals, and locks. A certain railway station may have 10 signals and 3 locks.

I have idea that `variable` should be used but this word does not convey proper sense.

Comment: Integer. Or integral as an adjective.

Comment: There isn't an "antonym" because there are lots of other types of variable. "Number of seats" is integer valued. "Horsepower" and "length" are continuous. "Fuel type" is one of a limited range of options - gasoline, diesel, electric etc. "Model name" can be anything.  The only antonym is the obvious "non-boolean".

Comment: @DJClayworth I agree that no antonym is possible. If the PO dislikes "non-Boolean", perhaps the features could be termed multivariates, by creating the adjectival noun "multivariate".

Comment: "Multivariate" excludes variables that have only two options, but are not boolean (e.g. fuel type= gasoline or diesel).

Comment: What would the logical opposite of boolean even be? Any positive integer above 1? Or would it include any lack of something above 1 (i.e. ...-1, 2 ...)? My point being: it seems you aren't looking for an antonym of boolean, but a word that includes additional possibilities.

Comment: *multiplicity* can 0..1  or 0..n  or 0..*

Comment: @Joachim: I'd say the opposition of ***boolean** [logic]* is ***fuzzy** logic* - it's the difference between "constrained to the discrete values 0/1, true/false, yes/no" and "continuously variable, analogue".

Comment: What about the antonym of "Boolean features" as "features with cardinality"?